# jQuery datepicker - Set display position of the calendar when displayed as an overlay

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Is there any way to specify where will the calendar be displayed when the related input gets the focus?

I didn't find a way of doing this in the doc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so one solution a coleague gave me for this was to comment out the jquery lines that position the calendar when it is displayed.